# Merge two similar PSObjects

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

after performing a Get-ADObject query i got two PSObjects (for 2 separate OUs), lets call them $query1 and $query2, which contain Member-Objects of type

```
Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
```

Now i want to merge those two PSObjects, $query1 and $query2, into one single PSObject that contains the ADObjects of both queries but i don't really know how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested this quickly with arrays and it should work with a collection of AD object (just don't have time to test that right now). If it does not, let me know, there is a more explicit if more verbose method.

```
$combined = @()
$combined += $query1
$combined += $query2
```

Comment: thats not what i want. if i do so, then i get another "level". In Fact, what i'm doing here is creating a new HashTable (PSObject) with the Keys Query1 and Query2 and the (old) PSObjects as their values. But i don't want this extra level.

Comment: Well it's not a HashTable. "into one single PSObject that contains the ADObjects " based on this, to "contain" the two objects, would by definition require another level for the container. If you mean that you want an object that has all the properties of thos objects, then you would essentially do the same thing but add each property one at a time.

Comment: You could even use the Get-Member cmdlet with the -MemberType parameter to list all the properties on one of the objects

Comment: Okay, so let me clearify: "I want one single PSObject that DIRECTLY (without another level) contains every single Member-Object (which are of type ADObject) of the two original PSObjects. I do not want a PSObject that contains two PSObjects which contain the ADObjects."

Iretation over the original PSObject using the Get-Member method dosn't do the trick for me, since i would have to add the Members into the new PSObject and assign ney $keys to them. However, maybe you're talking about another construct - an example would be great.

Comment: Oooh...I understand now. Sorry for the confusion. You said member and my brain heard object member (methods and properties) not AD OU members. I will ammend.